# Unable to get redirected to a page using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to redirect a user after login to a specific page but it's not getting redirected, I tried checking everything but the issue still exists. i get this error like the page name gets in red color in network section of inspect element.

[image]

i used the following  code:

```
$("#form-login").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/ajax_functions.php",
    data: $(this).serialize()+"&action=form-login",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
      window.location.replace(data.redirect_url);
    }
  });
});
```

ajax file contain the following code

```
$json = array("status" => 2, "message" => 'Successfully LoggedIn', "redirect_url" => site_url('dashboard'), "role" => $role);
```

and the site url function is as follows

```
function site_url($urlParam) {
    return SITE_URL.(($urlParam!="")?$urlParam:"");
}
```

please provide me the solution that how it will be redirected and where i'm going wrong.

Comment: In your success callback function, what does `data` look like when you inspect it?

Comment: put .done function and let us know what data you are receiving? Put error as well and just parse JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: @Kulix: {"status":2,"message":"Successfully LoggedIn","redirect_url":"des-online:8888\/dashboard","role":"ADMIN"}   this is what i get gron data

Comment: Are there any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: That url value is invalid. What is `des-online`? and there is no `//` so is being interpreted by browser as relative path

Comment: You need to add a base url to data.redirect_url. the base url of where this javascript is being served from. (IE locally it might look like http://localhost:8080 for example)

Comment: Can you confirm you are not already on `/dashboard` when this request is made? `location.replace` has a [specific use case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) and does not work in Chrome from my experience when the URL is the same as current location. Does `location = ` meet your needs? Why `replace`?

Comment: @charlietfl: des-online is the domain name you can say as i am working locally and im using mamp so the starting link is like (des-online:8888/dashboard)

Comment: but there is no protocol or a `//` for protocol relative. Look at the full path browser attempted to access in network.

Comment: @ficuscr: actually when my login is successfull i must get redirected to dashboard, but its not getting redirected it just stay on login page with no errors in console and dashboard in red color in network section, also i tried this as well ($(location).attr('href', data.redirect_url);)

Comment: Thank you friends it's done, actually i tried adding (http://) as a prefix in site_url variable and it worked for me.

Comment: That would be the protocol that charlietfl mentioned

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function *returns a string*, I.E. Strings are immutable and their methods do not change their value.

So, `window.location.replace(data.redirect_url)` would not actually change the `window.location`. Also, keep in mind that window.location is an *object*, not a string. However, if you did `window.location.href = data.redirect_url;`
You would redirect to `data.redirect_url`.

Good luck!